# Is it possible to access multiple levels of an object in Mustache / Hogan?

Tags: mustache, hogan.js

I have a json object that roughly looks like this:

```
data = \
{
   'id' : 10000 ,
   'title' : 'Sample Article',
   'authors' : [
       {
          'id' : 20000,
          'name' : 'John Doe'
       },
       {
          'id' : 20001,
          'name' : 'Jane Doe'
       }
   ]
}
```

While looping the data.authors , i need to simultaneously access both the root id (`data.id`) and the local id (`data.authors[author].id`)

Is this possible with Mustache ?

My current workaround is to just duplicate the data.id into data.article_id , as accessing variables a level up seem to be accessible in the spec and in practice.  i couldn't find anything regarding variable naming conditions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass the article in as a namespaced object, you can:

```
data = {
  article: {
    id: 10000,
    title: 'Sample Article',
    authors: [
      { id: 20000, name: 'John Doe' },
      { id: 20001, name: 'Jane Doe' }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
{{# article.authors }}
  Article ID: {{ article.id }}
  Author ID:  {{ id }}
{{/ article.authors }}
```

If you want to keep the "article" as the rendering context, wrap your whole template in an `{{# article }}` section, and you'll be able to refer to the authors as `{{# authors }}`, while still having access to `{{ article.id }}` when you need it.